# Merging Data from multiple sheets that contains formulas/cell references

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Sheet 1 Screenshot]

[image: Range Screenshot]

Hi all! I have posted the same question previously but this one time is more explained with screenshots of the file.

I have 85 sheets (Sheet 1 screenshot for reference) and a specified range for each sheet (I12:N42). But this range consists formulas & cell references. What I am trying to do is:

1. Copying the data from all the 85 sheets with this range (I12:N42) except if "Qty = 0".
2. Pasting the copied data by PasteValues only to a master sheet.

PS: I tried to do the same thing using Power Query but it is quite slow so maybe VBA code will work faster on this.

Appreciate you guys!

Comment: I can try preparing a piece of code using only arrays, but before that, I will like to clarify some issues: Are there other sheets in the workbook, except the 'master' and those 85? If you will copy **all them** in the range you mention, any new range will overwrite existing and only the last enumerated sheet values will remain. Should you mean starting from the 12th row and pasting to the next empty row, in case of the following? If  not, please try clarifying this aspect. I have a scenario in my mind, but I do not like wasting my time if the question is unclear, even if it looks challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It assumes that there are no other sheets except the master one and the mentioned 85 to copy from. If others, except them adding new conditions where the master one is skipped:

```
Sub copyNonZeroRowsInMaster()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, shM As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastRow As Long, boolOK As Boolean
    Dim arrRows, arrCopy, arr, arrSlice, count0 As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    
    lastRow = 2  'the initial row where to paste
    Set shM = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")  'please, use here the appropriate sheet name
    shM.Range("A2:F10000").ClearContents
           
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name <> shM.Name And sh.Name <> "TRACKING" Then             'if other sheets needs to be excepted, add them in the condition
            Set rng = sh.Range("K13:K42")         'the range being the reference for non zero values
            arrCopy = sh.Range("I13:N42").Value 'place all the range to be processed in an array, to make code faster
            count0 = Application.CountIf(rng, 0)   'count the zero values (even from formulas) to redim in the next row
            arr = rng.Value                     'place the reference range in an array (also, to make the code faster)
            If rng.Count - count0 = 0 Then GoTo OverProcessing
            ReDim arrRows(1 To rng.Count - count0, 1 To 1) 'redim the array to keep the row numbers without 0 in K:K
            k = 1: boolOK = False    'initialize the variable based on what the array keeping the rows to be copied is loaded
            For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate beteen the array elements
                 If arr(i, 1) <> 0 Then
                    arrRows(k, 1) = i: k = k + 1 'fill the rows to be copied number in the array
                    boolOK = True
                End If
            Next i
            If Not boolOK Then GoTo OverProcessing 'if there are only zero in all processed K:K range
            arrSlice = Application.Index(arrCopy, arrRows, Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) 'create a slice array keeping only the non zero rows
            'drop the slice array content at once:
            shM.Range("A" & lastRow).Resize(IIf(k = 2, UBound(arrRows), UBound(arrSlice)), 6).Value = arrSlice
            lastRow = shM.Range("A" & shM.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'recalculate the last empty row
        End If
OverProcessing:
    Next
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The code is not tested (except the principle of working) and it should be very fast. Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, I have tested your code and here is the result. I would say it is really, really fast in processing the data that I need. I just did some small changes with the code:
1. lastRow changed it to "2" so the results will be pasted in the 2nd row of the master sheet.
2. changed the range to "I13:N42" since the 13th row (headers) is no longer needed to be copied since it is already in the master sheet.
3. changed the initial row to paste the data from "I2" to "A2" as my master sheet is starting from "A" column.
But the result still shows some rows with "0" quantities.

Comment: Ex: Sheet #1 only has one row which value is not zero (0), but when I run the code, it pastes 2 rows (1st row with the correct data i needed, 2nd row with data showing "0" in the whole array). I want to share a screenshot here in the comment but i don't see the option.

Comment: @SoulSeeker916 If not something confidential, please share the workbook in discussion. You can send it on my personal mail (see my profile) or using a transfer site and place here the link. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used.

Comment: here is the link of the file https://easyupload.io/hqjajy

Comment: @SoulSeeker916 My code used to process the ranges as you stated in your question... Modifying the ranges (starting from I13 instead of I12) the modification should be applied to the reference range, too ("K12:K42"), and the code could be even simpler... checking for non zero cells should be done earlier and all the following iteration should be skipped for such a case. Otherwise, an error will occur when try `Redim 0 to 1, 1 to 1)`. I will adapt the above code to work as (I understood) you need. It is difficult to check the 86th sheets against the first, second and so on.

Comment: @SoulSeeker916 Adapted. Please, also check the updated workbook. You can download it from [here](https://easyupload.io/hm53yt) and send some feedback.

Comment: @SoulSeeker916 I am not sure that the previous sent workbook was saved. When I closed it it asked for saving. So, try [this link](https://easyupload.io/ks3ej9).

Comment: I actually did the same to change the range in K12:K42 and got the same output & got the error you mentioned. Regarding the adapted one while verifying the data, it seems that those sheets with only one row containing data is copied 6 times. Other sheets with 2 or more rows of data are perfect. When i counted the # of rows from all sheets, it has a total of 162 rows of data.

Comment: For Example: Sheet #69 (application # OND/618/21) has 1 row of data, but was pasted in the master sheet 6 times.

Comment: @SoulSeeker916 No time right now to check, but I will do it. Theoretically, is shouldn't be possible. I will try understanding where from the other 5 rows come.

Comment: @SoulSeeker916 You were right! It looks that slicing an array by an array of only one row, it (strangely) returns an array containing number of columns rows. I will adapt the code to deal with such a situation, too.

Comment: @SoulSeeker916 Adapted the code. Please, test it and send some feedback. Please, also download the processed workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/0ihdlp).

Comment: you are a life saver! It is now working perfectly fine and fast as well. Same time I am trying to learn your code specially those array slices which I do not have prior knowledge about it.

Comment: @SoulSeeker916 Glad I could help! I commented all code lines I thought may not be easily understood. If need further details, do not hesitate to (specifically) ask for clarifications. But, I will lake to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, sorry as I forgot to tick the CHECK mark for acceptance and now just did. Anyhow, since my workbook was done in a daily basis, there is a monthly workbook as well which then consolidates all the data from all the "MASTER" sheets of the daily workbook. Given that all these daily workbooks are on the same folder, I want to use the same code to consolidate all daily master sheets data into a monthly master sheet which is on a separate workbook. Idk if this is still relevant to my main question but hope it does.

Comment: PS: I only need the data from the "MASTER" sheet from each daily workbooks to be consolidated in a monthly master sheet in a separate workbook.